# Usage of interface in Go

Tags: interface, go

I would like to understand the interface type with a *simple* example of it's use in Go (Language).

I read the web documentation, but I don't get it.

Comment: Did you read this in the docs?? http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types. Also try this one http://diveintogo.blogspot.com/2010/03/classic-inheritance-in-go-lang.html

Comment: Yup, I read the docs... Thanks for the links

Comment: Usage of interface in Go? Decouple code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62297796/12817546. Call a method “dynamically”. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62336440/12817546. Access a Go package. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62278078/12817546. Assign any value to a variable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62337836/12817546.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The idea behind go interfaces is [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Which simply translates into: If you look like a duck and quack like a duck then you are a  duck. Meaning that if your object implements all duck's features then there should be no problem using it as a duck. Here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Walker interface {
    Walk() string
}

type Human string
type Dog string

func (human Human) Walk() string { //A human is a walker
    return "I'm a man and I walked!"
}

func (dog Dog) Walk() string { //A dog is a walker
    return "I'm a dog and I walked!"
}

//Make a walker walk
func MakeWalk(w Walker) {
    fmt.Println(w.Walk())
}

func main() {
    var human Human
    var dog Dog
    MakeWalk(human)
    MakeWalk(dog)
}
```

Here a `Human` is a `Walker` and a `Dog` is a `Walker`. Why? Because they both.. well... `Walk`. They both implement the `Walk () string` function. So this is why you can execute `MakeWalk` on them.

This is very helpful when you want different types to behave in the same manner. A practical example would be file type objects (sockets, file objects) - you need a Write and a Read function on all of them. Then you can use Write and Read in the same fashion independent of their type - which is cool.

Comment: Thanks! This is really what I wanted to know. Much clearer than in the go tutorial.

Comment: What benefits interfaces give in context of golang? If i'm using interfaces for 2 objects, and my interface has 3 methods, does that mean my 2 objects should implement these 3 methods?

Comment: @Avdept yes, you have to implement the same signature as the interface for your type. Not sure what you mean by benefit.

Comment: While explaining Go as having duck-typing can help people understand Go's interfaces, Go in-fact **does not** use duck-typing, which is a language feature that dynamic languages can have. Go instead uses Structural Typing since Go is statically-typed, as the Wikipedia the article OP linked [explains in one of its sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#Structural_type_systems).  #justfyi #fwiw

Answer (score 2):

Another working example showing the interaction between an interface and a structure

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Info interface {
  Noofchar() int
  Increment()
}

type Testinfo struct {
  noofchar int     
}

func (x *Testinfo) Noofchar() int {
  return x.noofchar
}
func (x *Testinfo) Increment() {
  x.noofchar++
}

func main(){
  var t Info = &Testinfo{noofchar:1}
  fmt.Println("No of char ",t.Noofchar())
  t.Increment()
  fmt.Println("No of char ",t.Noofchar())
}
```

Comment: @Speccy i had to google that term. For anyone wondering it means magician/wizard

Answer (score 0):

To add to the excellent answer by @AlexPlugaru here and by @NickCraig-Wood at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18854285/12817546.

```
package main

import . "fmt"

func main() {
    cat("Bird").Eat()      // Bird
    eater.Eat(cat("Milk")) // Milk
    Break(cat("Fish"))     // Fish
    Lunch().Eat()          // Mice
    Tea(true)           // Bird
}

type cat string
type eater interface{ Eat() }

func (c cat) Eat()  { Println(c) }
func Break(e eater) { e.Eat() }
func Lunch() eater  { return cat("Mice") }
func Tea(b bool) {
    if b {
        cat("Bird").Eat()
    }
}
```

Methods on a struct or any other concrete type are resolved statically. See `cat("Bird").Eat()` and `eater.Eat(cat("Milk"))`. The only way to have dynamically dispatched methods is through an interface. See `Break(cat("Fish"))` and `Lunch().Eat()`, http://www.golangbr.org/doc/faq#How_do_I_get_dynamic_dispatch_of_methods.

`Tea(true)` calls a method dynamically without using an interface. See https://talks.golang.org/2014/taste.slide#19. But interfaces—by design and convention—encourage us to write composable code. See https://talks.golang.org/2014/go4gophers.slide#21.

The result: simple pieces connected by small interfaces. See https://talks.golang.org/2012/chat.slide#5. Better to have many small simple things than one big complex thing. See https://talks.golang.org/2014/go4gophers.slide#24.

You can also hide anything in a private package and just expose specific types, interfaces, and factory functions. See `Break(cat("Fish"))` and `Lunch().Eat()`, https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/lets-go-object-oriented-programming-in-golang--cms-26540

Comment: Decouple code with an interface. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62297796/12817546. Call a method “dynamically”. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62336440/12817546. Access a Go package. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62278078/12817546. Assign any value to a variable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62337836/12817546.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I'm using the interface to demonstrate how to achieve polymorphism in Golang.

```
package main 


import(
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main(){
    rect := Rectangle{20,50}
    cir := Circle{2}

    //According to object you passed in getArea method, 
    // it will change the behaviour and that is called Polymorphism.
    fmt.Println("Area of Rectangle =",getArea(rect))
    fmt.Println("Area of Circle =",getArea(cir))

}

//Interface Shape with one area method
type Shape interface{
     area() float64
}

//Creating Rectangle and Circle type using struct 
type Rectangle struct{
    height float64
    width float64
}

type Circle struct{
    radius float64
}

//Receiver function, which implements struct's area methods
func(r Rectangle) area() float64{
    return r.height * r.width
}

func(c Circle) area() float64{
    return math.Pi * math.Pow(c.radius,2)
}

//passing interface as arguments, which can calculate shape of any mentioned type
//All the struct are tied together because of the Interface.
func getArea(shape Shape) float64{
    return shape.area()
}
```