# Can you explain Go Interfaces?

Tags: go

I dont get the whole types + Interfaces model(that replaces classes in other languages). If theres a simple way you could explain what they are about, it will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain Go Interfaces? Decouple code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62297796/12817546. Call a method “dynamically”. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62336440/12817546. Access a Go package. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62278078/12817546. Assign any value to a variable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62337836/12817546.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go interfaces are statically checked duck typing.

The difference between pure virtual classes in C++ or interfaces in java is that you don't declare the interface on the class that implements the interface, but on the method that *receives* the interface.

For example, I can create an interface with a `Read` and a `Write` method and call it `ThingsDustinReadsAndWrites` and have a function called `doReadsAndWrites(rr ThingsDustinReadsAndWrites`.  That can, in turn, receive a built-in `http.ClientConn` which has never heard of my interface, but implements it because it happens to have those methods.

Answer (score 5):

This is a pretty good overview:

http://research.swtch.com/2009/12/go-data-structures-interfaces.html