# Understanding Interface

Tags: interface, go, go-interface

I am a newbie in Go lang , I was trying to understand Go Interface by writing a simple piece of code . I am getting an error , as I am not able to understand the correct way of referring to a Interface method kindly tell me where I am going wrong.

```
type Info interface {
Noofchar() int
}

type Testinfo struct {
noofchar int
}

func (x Testinfo)Noofchar() int {
return x.noofchar
}

func main(){
var t Info
fmt.Println(x.Testinfo)
fmt.Println("No of char ",t.Noofchar())
x.noofchar++
fmt.Println("No of char ",t.Noofchar())
}
```

Am I referring to the method correctly by t.Noofchar() ? or there is something else that I am missing

Comment: Understanding Interface? Decouple code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62297796/12817546. Call a method “dynamically”. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62336440/12817546. Access a Go package. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62278078/12817546. Assign any value to a variable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62337836/12817546.

Answer (score 3):

Methods typically receive pointers to a struct.

```
func (x Testinfo)Noofchar() int {
```

changed to

```
func (x *Testinfo)Noofchar() int {
```

Took out `var x Info` in the beginning, refactored your `main()` just a bit and the resulting code in play is:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Info interface {
    Noofchar() int
    Increment()
}

type Testinfo struct {
    noofchar int
}

func (x *Testinfo) Noofchar() int {
    return x.noofchar
}
func (x *Testinfo) Increment() {
    x.noofchar++
}

func main(){
    var t Info = &Testinfo{noofchar:1}
    fmt.Println("No of char ",t.Noofchar())
    t.Increment()
    fmt.Println("No of char ",t.Noofchar())
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/6D-LzzYYMU

In your example you modify `x` directly.  If you're passing an interface around, you don't have access to the underlying data structures, only the methods.  So I changed your direct increment to an `Increment()` method.

Comment: It's not a requirement that methods are defined on pointers to structs. They can be defined on the struct values themselves, but of course methods like your `Increment` will have no effect on the original if it's not defined on a pointer.

Comment: @Daniel What if I want to use a struct member (eg noofchar) in some other function (whose defination is not in Interface ) ??

Comment: ...also, to illustrate interfaces, you should really do `var t Info = &Testinfo{noofchar:1}`. Right now, the `noofchar` can be reached from `t`.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is a variable to which you can assign anything that implements the `Info` interface. You've assigned nothing to that variable.

Once you assign something, `x.noofchar++` will not work because again `x` can hold anything that implements the `Info` interface, which means you can only access the methods defined by that interface.  Interfaces do not allow direct access to fields.

The only method defined in the `Info` interface is the `Noofchar() int` method, so that is the only way to interact with the value stored in `x`.

The `x` defined by the method receiver `(x Testinfo)` isn't at all related to the `var x Info` variable. That `x` *does* have direct access to the struct fields.

The `t.Noofchar()` calls are correct and will work.