# Struggling to See the Purpose of an Interface Type

Tags: interface, go

I've recently taken a liking to the Go programming language, I've found it wonderful so far but am really struggling to understand interfaces. I've read about quite a bit about them, but they still seem very abstract to me.

I've wrote a quick bit of code that uses an interface below:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "math"
)

type Circer interface {
    Circ() float64
}

type Square struct {
    side float64
}

type Circle struct {
    diam, rad float64
}

func (s *Square) Circ() float64 {
    return s.side * 4
}

func (c *Circle) Circ() float64 {
    return c.diam * math.Pi
}

func (c *Circle) Area() float64 {
    if c.rad == 0 {
        var rad = c.diam / 2
        return (rad*rad) * math.Pi
    } else {
        return (c.rad*c.rad) * math.Pi
    }
}

func main() {

    var s = new(Square)
    var c = new(Circle)

    s.side = 2
    c.diam = 10

    var i Circer = s

    fmt.Println("Square Circ: ", i.Circ())

    i = c

    fmt.Println("Circle Circ: ", i.Circ())
}
```

I can't really see the purpose of the Circer interface. The methods are already written and I could save two lines of code by simply calling them directly on the structs, rather than using Circer as a wrapper.

Is there something I'm missing? Am I using the interface incorrectly? Any help or examples are appreciated.

Comment: Purpose of an Interface Type? Decouple code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62297796/12817546. Call a method “dynamically”. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62336440/12817546. Access a Go package. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62278078/12817546. Assign any value to a variable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62337836/12817546.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point of interfaces is that you can make general purpose functions like `ShowMeTheCircumference` below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Circer interface {
    Circ() float64
}

type Square struct {
    side float64
}

type Circle struct {
    diam, rad float64
}

func (s *Square) Circ() float64 {
    return s.side * 4
}

func (c *Circle) Circ() float64 {
    return c.diam * math.Pi
}

func ShowMeTheCircumference(name string, shape Circer) {
    fmt.Printf("Circumference of %s is %f\n", name, shape.Circ())
}

func main() {
    square := &Square{side: 2}
    circle := &Circle{diam: 10}
    ShowMeTheCircumference("square", square)
    ShowMeTheCircumference("circle", circle)

}
```

[Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/xFj_W4FDwX)

Comment: I liked your "general-purpose" function nomenclature. I quoted your answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62336440/12817546

Answer (score 4):

What you're missing are scenarios where you *can't* know statically what kind of thing you have on hand.  Let's get concrete.

Think of [`io.Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), for example.  There are lots of things that implement the `read` method of the interface.  Say that you write a program that uses `io.Reader`.  For example, a program might print an MD5-sum of the content in a `io.Reader`.

```
package mypackage

import (
    "fmt"
    "crypto/md5"
    "io"
    "strings"
)

func PrintHashsum(thing io.Reader) {
    hash := md5.New()
    io.Copy(hash, thing)
    fmt.Println("The hash sum is:", hash.Sum(nil))
}
```

and say that you use this `mypackage` in another file elsewhere:

```
func main() {
    mypackage.PrintHashsum(strings.NewReader("Hello world"))
}
```

Now say that you use an implementation of an `io.Reader` that decompresses zip files on the fly, such as the one in the [`archive/zip`](http://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/) package.

```
import "archive/zip"
// ... 
func main() {
    // ...
    anotherReader = zip.NewReader(...)
    // ...
}
```

Due to how interfaces work, you can feed such a zip-sourced reader into the MD5-sum computing `mypackage.PrintHashsum` function without doing anything else to its existing code or recompiling `mypackage`!

```
func main() {
    // ...
    anotherReader = zip.NewReader(...)
    mypackage.PrintHashsum(anotherReader)
}
```

Interfaces have everything to do with letting programs be open to dynamic extension.  In your example, you might argue that the compiler should just know exactly what method should be called.  But in cases where your compiler supports separate compilation (like Go) for speed, the compiler can't possibly know: at the point of compiling `mypackage`, the compiler can't see all the possible implementations of `io.Reader`: it's not a mind reader or time traveler!

Answer (score 2):

**"We demand rigidly defined areas of doubt and uncertainty!"**
*- Douglas Adams, The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*

In order to understand Interfaces in Go, we must first understand why we program to Interfaces in general.

### Separating the what from the how

We use interfaces to hide implementation details behind an abstraction. We like to hide these details because the details (i.e. the how) are more likely to change than the abstraction and because it allows us to extend and change our applications without having the change ripple throughout our programs.  When a consumer depends on an Interface instead of a concrete type, they are **decoupling their program** from the implementation details behind the Interface which **shelters the consumer from change and makes it easier to test, extend, and maintain** their application.

### Golang Interfaces

Go has a very powerful Interface implementation.  As in most languages, it provides a way to specify the behavior of an object through an abstraction so that any place the abstraction is used **any** implementation of that abstraction can be used, but in Go there is no need to explicitly declare that your concretion implements a given Interface as Go handles this automatically.

Removing the explicit declaration requirement has interesting ramifications, such as: you can let your program surface the Interfaces as you go to help you identify the appropriate abstractions, without needing to annotate all of the implementations as you discover them.  This also means Interfaces that are created for Testing does not need to pollute your implementation code.  Additionally, there isn't an explicit relationship between the Interface and the implementer, so the implementer has no dependency/coupling in that direction.

### The Circer Interface example

In the example you've provided it is certainly simpler and easier to avoid the complexity and "cognitive load" of using an Interface instead of binding to the implementation (concretion).  In most trivial examples it can seem like dogmatic over engineering to use an interface.

### Summary

Interfaces are a powerful way for us to decouple our applications to make it easier for them to grow over time.  If you *anticipate change/variation* (and need to protect your application from that change/variation) then creating and depending on an Interface is a step in the right direction.

**For more...**

See this "good" [Go Object Oriented Design post](http://nathany.com/good/).

And take a look at the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) [design principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod), as it is an excellent place to start when considering the implications of abstraction and managing dependencies and change.

Comment: This is how Java interfaces are used, but I think Go interfaces aren't idiomatically used to allow future variation of implementations. Instead, they're introduced only when they're needed. Take a look at the standard library; it's packed with concrete types where Java style would be to use an interface. Eg: http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/response.go?s=489:2363#L17

Comment: Go will absolutely allow consumers to depend on the abstraction instead of the concretion, and the Go standard library does quite often.  You pointed to the Response struct, which encapsulates state and not behavior, and I was discussing the power of abstraction to decouple from concrete behavior.  Take a look at http://golang.org/src/pkg/io/io.go which is used within http response lib.  I completely disagree that it is idiomatic Go to not use Interfaces to protect from variation.