# Golang interface benefits

Tags: go, types, interface

I read about the interfaces a lot and I think I understand how it works. I read about the `interface{}` type and use it to take an argument of function. It is clear. My question (and what I don't understand) is what is my benefit if I am using it. It is possible I didn't get it entirely but for example I have this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func PrintAll(vals []interface{}) {
    for _, val := range vals {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}

func main() {
    names := []string{"stanley", "david", "oscar"}
    vals := make([]interface{}, len(names))
    for i, v := range names {
        vals[i] = v
    }
    PrintAll(vals)
}
```

Why is it better than this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func PrintAll(vals []string) {
    for _, val := range vals {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}

func main() {
    names := []string{"stanley", "david", "oscar"}
    PrintAll(names)
}
```

Comment: Use an interface when you may way to change out the underlying implementation, but not change all the code that uses it.

Comment: What is the  benefit of using an interface? Decouple code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62297796/12817546. Call a method “dynamically”. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62336440/12817546. Access a Go package. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62278078/12817546. Assign any value to a variable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62337836/12817546.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're always want to print `string` values, then the first using `[]interface{}` is not better at all, it's worse as you lose some compile-time checking: it won't warn you if you pass a slice which contains values other than `string`s.

If you want to print values other than `string`s, then the second with `[]string` wouldn't even compile.

For example the first also handles this:

```
PrintAll([]interface{}{"one", 2, 3.3})
```

While the 2nd would give you a compile-time error:

> cannot use []interface {} literal (type []interface {}) as type []string in argument to PrintAll

The 2nd gives you compile-time guarantee that only a slice of type `[]string` is passed; should you attempt to pass anything other will result in compile-time error.

Also see related question: [Why are interfaces needed in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092925/why-are-interfaces-needed-in-golang)

Comment: Thank you. Can you please say a brief real world example? It is okay, just I can't imagine how can I use the interface{} benefits in a real world problem.

Comment: @PumpkinSeed [`fmt.Println()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) which you call in your example also takes values of `interface{}` type, which means you can pass any value to it.