# Calling a function that takes an interface as a parameter in Go

Tags: go

How do you construct an interface as a parameter to a function?

```
type blahinterface interface {
    method1()
    method2()
    method3()
}

func blah (i blahinterface) {

}


blah(?)  < what goes in here
```

Comment: Please try to go though [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) and [A Tour of Go](http://tour.golang.org/)

Comment: Partial to [the Go Wikipedia article's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(programming_language)#Interface_system) interfaces example, but yeah, you need to read up, yo.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you try to put anything "in here", the compiler will tell you precisely what is missing:

```
type S struct{}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    s := &S{}
    blah(s)
}
```

A `go build` [on this example](http://play.golang.org/p/S5PQNdhLD3) would tell you:

```
prog.go:20: cannot use s (type *S) as type blahinterface in argument to blah:
    *S does not implement blahinterface (missing method1 method)
 [process exited with non-zero status]
```

But with:

```
func (s *S) method1(){}
func (s *S) method2(){}
func (s *S) method3(){}
```

The [program do compile just fine](http://play.golang.org/p/_thEPEvpex).

So even without **[reading about interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11753508/6309)**, you are guided and can guess what is missing.